# How do i change the header location in PHP to redirect to a subdomain?

Tags: php, redirect, header

how can i make a PHP script to use the header location feature and redirect the user to my sub-domain?

I've tried the meta refresh thing but that looks a little strange having it in a echo... I need something fast and not clunky, So i turned to headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to make a redirect in PHP using headers? Not hard. No extra code is needed to redirect to a subdomain.

Try the code below:

```
<? die(header('Location: http://mysubdomain.example.net/')); ?>
```

You can change the `http://mysubdomain.example.net/`